# Is Low Seg2Cat working correctly?

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat, low

I am trying to grab the category ID from the last segment to use in a redirect back to that category page but nothing is showing up.

My main page is http://domain.com/store/shop/C28, then you click to view a single entry.

the entry is http://domain.com/store/product_detail/158

where 158 is the entry_id to display a dynamic entry showing one product.

In my redirect (after adding the product to a cart) I want to go back to http://domain.com/store/shop/C28

I have tried to use this in my add to cart but nothing is parsing for the seg2cat

```
return="http://hookingrugs.com/store/shop/C{last_segment_category_id}"}
```

When I view source I just see http://hookingrugs.com/store/shop/C"

with no ID.

Even if I just place {last_segment_category_id} on the page outside of any other tags I still get nothing.  Why does low seg2cat not pick up on the last entry ID.

Comment: Have you tried passing {last_segment_category_id} as an embedded variable?

Comment: how would I do that?  Shouldn't it work just on the page not inside of any tags?  Is my issue that I am using 

<a href="{entry_id_path='store/product_detail/'}">

Comment: Is the category group which this category belongs to enabled? CP Home > Extensions > Low Seg2Cat > Extension Settings

Comment: IT was set to ALL

Answer (score 4):

Low Seg2Cat doesn't pick-up category information associated with **channel entry IDs** in the URL - it picks up category information associated with **category URL titles** in the URL.

So, it is working, but it doesn't do what you thought it might do.

Comment: that is what I was guessing entry_id vs url_title

Comment: So if I am on this page http://domain.com/store/shop/C28

Shouldn't I be able to use:
{last_segment_category_name}
{last_segment_category_description}

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: doesn't work with C28 but DOES work when using category_url_title as the segment..  Problem is low seg2cat does not offer {last_segment_category_url_title}

Comment: this was my only option        return="http://domain.com/store/shop/category/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}"}

Comment: Low Seg2Cat only works with category URL titles in the URI, not with cat IDs like C28. It also doesn't offer {last_segment_category_url_title}, as that would be identical to the native {last_segment}. So the add-on appears to be working as designed.